# Logging in with IdentityServer with custom client-side log in page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have a setup of [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) with configuration of a client with hybrid flow. Is it possible to have an ASP.NET MVC app to use this instance of IdentityServer to log-in the user without looping to IdentityServer's log-in page? That is, use a custom log-in page on the client side to get user credentials and then make a server-side connection with IdentityServer to do the authorization? Is there any sample that demonstrates this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how I interpret your question, the Resource Owner Password Credential Flow seems to fit your scenario.

See the FAQ-like answer [here](https://gist.github.com/jawadatgithub/638c11f08ecc0d76b05c#user-content-q-which-flow-types-designed-to-be-used-only-in-trusted-environment-like-backend-rest-api-micro-services-isolated-from-internet-or-owned-serversdevices-in-general--trusted-oauth2-clients).

"Q. Which Flow Types designed to be used ONLY in trusted environment (like backend REST API/ micro-services isolated from internet, or owned servers/devices, in general: trusted OAuth2 clients)?

A.

Resource Owner Password Credential Flow (ROPCF) [it involve human: app show its own login page then pass user/pass... to STS].
Client Credential flow [machine to machine (API to API): supply client-id and secret]."

*Disclaimer - I understand you are currently using Hybrid flow- My answer simply implies you could change your solution. If that is not possible, then I would suggest looking into multiple OAuth implementations for an MVC app.

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't get an answer for this, I'm just posting what I've found so far.

It looks like it is not possible to bypass the IdentityServer's log-in page.

For more info about IdentityServer flows see: [OIDC and OAuth2 Flows](https://gist.github.com/jawadatgithub/638c11f08ecc0d76b05c)